# Thicknesser won't engage cutters

Tags: tool-repair

I have a new BOYE 8" jointer / thicknesser that I bought cheap as it had a fault.   The company sold it "As Is" and the guys said the roller was a little stiff and won't move up and down easierly.  I thought ... Sounds easy.  Anyway, the jointer works great but the thicknesser isn't cutting.  The blade is set correctly and the rollers do roll.  When I raise the bed, it ends up spinning the rollers and the wood stalls.  The cutters still don't touch the wood?  Can anyone help?[image]

Comment: Do you have a model number? My first thought is to find the service manual online. I'm having trouble finding information about this brand online after a quick google search; "Boye" brings up knitting supplies. A picture might help here; often the same machine is imported by different companies and resold under a variety of badges.

Comment: Thanks Charley, ive added a photo and yes, I've seen a bunch of similar models around.  This model number is MBY8X.  I'll check online for a better manual as my owners manual says nothing about this.

Comment: Thanks, that's helpful. When you're done jointing and ready to plane, what procedure have you followed to convert the machine from jointer mode into planer mode?

Comment: I only need to remove the fence, relocate the dust shroud to the top and I should be good to go.  This is very frustrating.  Any help you can give mate would be awesome.  Someone said that one of the rollers was tight to move up and down - it does but not as freely as the first drive roller.  I've looked at adjustments for these rollers and there are none.